# Best data structure for my sudoku solver?

Tags: java, sudoku

I am building a sudoku solver. I built one in Python about a year ago and I really liked the way I had my data organized. What I did in python was as follows:

- Each row was a letter, each column was a number.
  (So top left cell was 'A1', bottom right cell was 'I9', top right 'A9', etc.)
- These 'cell names' were used as keys in a dictionary.
- The values attached to each key represented all the possible values that cell could legally store (according to the rules of sudoku). So each key had a starting value of '123456789'.
- I had other lists representing which cells were 'brothers'. (same row/column/3x3 box). If a cell had been 'solved' then its value in the dict would be reduced to only the integer it had been solved to.
- Any 'brother' cells to a solved cell would then have that 'solved' integer removed from their dictionary values. (it is no longer a potential value for that cell)
- Whenever a key's value was of length 1, that would represent a 'solved' cell.

For example, say 'A3' had been solved for 8. It would have key:value in the dict as 'A3': '8'. My methods would notice this and for every 'brother' cell (all the 'Ax' cells, all the 'y3' cells, and the 3x3 box 'A3' is in (A1-3,B1-3,C1-3) would have '8' removed from their values.
Say 'B2': '1234789' before 'A3' became '8'. Afterwards, 'B2': '123479'

Here's an example of a partially solved puzzle and how it would have been stored in my python code:

```
{'I6': '123456789', 'H9': '2', 'I2': '3', 'E8': '123456789', 'H3': '5', 'H7': '123456789', 'I7':
    '123456789', 'I4': '1', 'H5': '4', 'F9': '123456789', 'G7': '123456789', 'G6': '123456789', 'G5': '2',
    'E1': '4', 'G3': '9', 'G2': '4', 'G1': '6', 'I1': '2', 'C8': '123456789', 'I3': '7', 'E5': '1', 'I5':
    '123456789', 'C9': '7', 'G9': '123456789', 'G8': '8', 'A1': '7', 'A3': '123456789', 'A2': '6', 'A5':
    '123456789', 'A4': '2', 'A7': '123456789', 'A6': '123456789', 'C3': '123456789', 'C2': '123456789',
    'C1': '3', 'E6': '123456789', 'C7': '123456789', 'C6': '4', 'C5': '5', 'C4': '123456789', 'I9':
    '123456789', 'D8': '123456789', 'I8': '123456789', 'E4': '123456789', 'D9': '123456789', 'H8':
    '7', 'F6': '123456789', 'A9': '123456789', 'G4': '123456789', 'A8': '5', 'E7': '5', 'E3': '6',
    'F1': '123456789', 'F2': '123456789', 'F3': '123456789', 'F4': '123456789', 'F5': '3', 'E2':
    '7', 'F7': '7', 'F8': '123456789', 'D2': '5', 'H1': '1', 'H6': '6', 'H2': '8', 'H4': '3',
    'D3': '3', 'B4': '123456789', 'B5': '6', 'B6': '123456789', 'B7': '123456789', 'E9':
    '123456789', 'B1': '5', 'B2': '123456789', 'B3': '123456789', 'D6': '123456789', 'D7':
    '123456789', 'D4': '123456789', 'D5': '7', 'B8': '123456789', 'B9': '123456789', 'D1': '8'}
```

I can't quite figure out how I can set this up in Java. I don't have any experience with HashMaps, but from reading up on them, it seems like they could be a good candidate to fill the role of my Dictionary. If I go that route, what are some different ways I can go about storing the values within the HashMap (default '123456789', but with the ability to remove a specific number from the value anytime it becomes invalid due to a 'brother' cell having ONLY that specific number in its value).

Sorry if this is confusing and thank you to anyone who reads it. Once I get the data structures in place, I have a good grasp on how I will go about creating methods to 'whittle' down each cell's POTENTIAL_VALUES (values in the dict) until each cell (key) only has one value left (signifying a solved puzzle).

Comment: Stackoverflow is neither the place to learn about data structures and their corresponding strengths and weakness, or the basics of the Java programming language

Comment: This question is not suitable for Stackoverflow; It is too broad as there are too many possible answers.

Comment: You can just make your own. Java doesn't have special datastructures for sudokus that have 2-3 different layers of logic.

Comment: Try to cut the question some slack then and bring it to the point. I have got data of this format (small example with 2 datapoints), I wonder whether I should use a HashMap, ArrayList, Arrays or what ? I personally think that xy would be the best choice but I'm uncertain about quality xy of that choice.

Answer (score 1):

A list of possibilities would be best represented by a set.

```
Set<Integer>
```

A dictionary of cells to possibilities translates naturally to a map.

```
Map<Cell, Set<Integer>>
```

Note that I've used abstract `Set` and `Map` types rather than concrete implementations. You'll need to pick concrete classes to instantiate the variables with, but the variable types should use the abstract types. Here's what I mean:

```
Map<Cell, Set<Integer>> cellValues = new HashMap<>();

for (Cell cell: Cell.all()) {
    cellValues.put(cell, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)));
}
```

`HashMap` and `HashSet` are the concrete classes.

Note also that I've used a `Cell` class instead of working directly with strings like `"A1"`. In Python it's easy to work with strings and would probably be overkill to create a separate class. In Java it's definitely a good practice to create a `Cell` class.